# Android collapses a negatively aligned to view specifically when within ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, sdk, margin

is anyone able to tell me why the following layout doesn't render properly on Android API 16 and 17. (The red bar doesn't appear)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFAA00">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/redRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
            android:background="#AAFF0000"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/redRow"
            android:background="#AA00FF00"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Incorrect rendering on API 16 and 17
[image: Incorrect rendering on API 16 and 17]

Expected, as of API 18 and above
[image: Expected, as of API 18 and above]

Comment: What is not working? Can you provide some `screenshots`?

Comment: Screenshots added, as you can see the "below" alignment appears to be lost in a really odd way. Oddly enough having a negative marginTop on the other element doesn't trigger the issue.

Comment: The negative marginBottom is some part which API 16 and 17 doesn't like, but the answer I'm looking for is why? Some answer as to why this issue is triggered when within a ScrollView and when aligning to something else...